# How to implement inbuilt Bullet List within TextArea using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bulletedlist

i have used following code form jsfiddle.net but it have one bug that if we press Enter Key + Character keys very swiftly it generate following out put.

//Javascript Code

```
function onfoc()
{
if(document.getElementById('todolist').value =="")
{
    document.getElementById('todolist').value +='• ';
}
}

function bulletOnEnter(){
var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
if(keycode == '13'){

    document.getElementById("todolist").value +='• ';

}
var txtval = document.getElementById('todolist').value;
if(txtval.substr(txtval.length - 1) == '\n'){
    document.getElementById('todolist').value = txtval.substring(0,txtval.length - 1);
}
}
```

[Output Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/22hgf.jpg)

Comment: Why not use an unordered list ? Use `<ul>` and simply append an `li` element to the unordered list on keypress.

Comment: you are right but Application Layout will be violated if i do so. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this using an unordered list:

Html:

```
<ul id="todo">
  <li>stuff</li>
  <li>More stuff</li>
</ul>
<input id="addItems" type="text" />
```

Since you said you're using jQuery, you can simply append another list element with the current value of the text box and then it clears it.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //event listener
  $('#addItems').on('keypress', function(event){
    if(event.which === 13){
      event.preventDefault();
      var text = $('#addItems').val();
      $('#todo').append('<li>' + text + '</li>');
      //clear textbox
      $('#addItems').val('');
    }
  });
});
```

JSFiddle :  https://jsfiddle.net/k9hx7pdf/

Edit:
You can add `contenteditable="true"` to then edit each individual list item

Comment: Its really good solution #ZachPerkitny but its strict requirement that i must use textarea only. It will be great if you can help in textarea.